# How to send test execution report (report.html) from jenkins by using Slack notification add-on

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops, slack-api

I just installed the slack notification add-on in Jenkins and I can get notification if the build is success/failed as like below:

[image]

I wanna add few more things here since I'm very new to this implementation and looking help from experts.

1. I just wanna add test execution report (.htm) file and send it into this channel along with build number and job URL.
2. If the build is failed. I just want to capture the build failed message from console log and need to send that message to slack channel instead of saying the build failed.

Can someone help me to achieve this?

I just tried the notification but don't know how to attach the html report and add custom message for failed jobs. If there is any reference that will be very helpful.